# Target function and dynamic variable values in ImageSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, slider

I'm asking this question yet another time...
I have thumbnails, upon clicking which I need a more detailed version to open, with next/previous navigation buttons. Generally speaking, it works - when I click a thumbnail 5 (for example) - slide 5 opens. BUT! When I click 'next' - the image slider count kicks in and the second slide opens, as if the originally displayed one had an index of 1. Now, since the openning of an expanded version is triggered by 'target', is there a way to dynamically define the image counter (CurrentIndex) using target?

And the html is:

```
<div id="rooms">   
<ul id="check-rooms">

  <li class="room_c"><div class="room_list" data-room="one"><img src="site-assets/photos/rooms1.jpg"><div class="room-description"><span class="label_bold">Эконом</span><br><span class="desc"> Две кровати</span></div><div class="room_box"><a href="/photos"><span class="camera_left"><img src="site-assets/camera_icon.png" style="height: 16px; width: auto; position: relative;"></span></a><span class="camera_right"><div class="room_mdts" data-room="one" title="Номер класса Эконом">Дополнительная информация</div></span></div></div></li> 
  <li class="room_c"><div class="room_list" data-room="two"><img src="site-assets/photos/rooms2.jpg"><div class="room-description"><span class="label_bold">Стандарт</span><br><span class="desc">Двойная кровать</span></div><div class="room_box"><a href="/photos"><span class="camera_left"><img src="site-assets/camera_icon.png" style="height: 16px; width: auto; position: relative;"></span></a><span class="camera_right"><div class="room_mdts" data-room="two" title="Номер класса Стандарт">Дополнительная информация</div></span></div></div></li>  
   <li class="room_c extra"><div class="room_list" data-room="three"><img src="site-assets/photos/rooms2.jpg"><div class="room-description"><span class="label_bold">Стандарт</span><br><span class="desc">Две кровати</span></div><div class="room_box"><a href="/photos"><span class="camera_left"><img src="site-assets/camera_icon.png" style="height: 16px; width: auto; position: relative;"></span></a><span class="camera_right"><div class="room_mdts" data-room="three" title="Номер класса Стандарт">Дополнительная информация</div></span></div></div></li>  
   <li class="room_c extra"><div class="room_list" data-room="four"><img src="room-category/attic/img1.jpg"><div class="room-description"><span class="label_bold">Эконом мансарда</span><br><span class="desc">Двойная кровать</span></div><div class="room_box"><a href="/photos"><span class="camera_left"><img src="site-assets/camera_icon.png" style="height: 16px; width: auto; position: relative;"></span></a><span class="camera_right"><div class="room_mdts" data-room="four" title="Номер класса Люкс">Дополнительная информация</div></span></div></div></li> 
   <li class="room_c extra"><div class="room_list" data-room="five"><img src="room-category/attic/img1.jpg"><div class="room-description"><span class="label_bold">Эконом мансарда</span><br><span class="desc">Две кровати</span></div><div class="room_box"><a href="/photos"><span class="camera_left"><img src="site-assets/camera_icon.png" style="height: 16px; width: auto; position: relative;"></span></a><span class="camera_right"><div class="room_mdts" data-room="five" title="Номер класса Люкс">Дополнительная информация</div></span></div></div></li> 
  <li class="room_c"><div class="room_list" data-room="six"><img src="site-assets/photos/rooms3.jpg"><div class="room-description"><span class="label_bold">Люкс</span><br><span class="desc">Двойная кровать </span></div><div class="room_box"><a href="/photos"><span class="camera_left"><img src="site-assets/camera_icon.png" style="height: 16px; width: auto; position: relative;"></span></a><span class="camera_right"><div class="room_mdts" data-room="six" title="Номер класса Люкс">Дополнительная информация</div></span></div></div></li> 
   <li class="room_c extra"><div class="room_list" data-room="seven"><img src="site-assets/photos/rooms3.jpg"><div class="room-description"><span class="label_bold">Люкс</span><br><span class="desc">Две кровати</span></div><div class="room_box"><a href="/photos"><span class="camera_left"><img src="site-assets/camera_icon.png" style="height: 16px; width: auto; position: relative;"></span></a><span class="camera_right"><div class="room_mdts" data-room="seven" title="Номер класса Люкс">Дополнительная информация</div></span></div></div></li> 
  <li class="room_c extra"><div class="room_list" data-room="eight"><img src="room-category/neweds/IMG_9441.JPG"><div class="room-description"><span class="label_bold">Люкс Свадебный</span><br><span class="desc">Двойная кровать</span></div><div class="room_box"><a href="/photos"><span class="camera_left"><img src="site-assets/camera_icon.png" style="height: 16px; width: auto; position: relative;"></span></a><span class="camera_right"><div class="room_mdts" data-room="eight" title="Номер класса Люкс Свадебный">Дополнительная информация</div></span></div></div></li> 
  <li class="room_c extra"><div class="room_list" data-room="nine"><img src="site-assets/photos/7.jpg"><div class="room-description"><span class="label_bold">Лакшери (Супер Люкс)</span><br><span class="desc">Двойная кровать</span></div><div class="room_box"><a href="/photos"><span class="camera_left"><img src="site-assets/camera_icon.png" style="height: 16px; width: auto; position: relative;"></span></a><span class="camera_right"><div class="room_mdts" data-room="nine" title="Номер класса Люкс Свадебный">Дополнительная информация</div></span></div></div></li> 

</ul>



</div>

 <div class="button open"><span>Больше номеров</span><span class="icon-plus"><img src="site-assets/icon-plus.png" style="height: 0.9em;"></span></div>
 <div class="button close"><span>Скрыть</span><span class="icon-minus"><img src="site-assets/icon-minus.png" style="height: 0.9em;"></span></div>



</div>


<div class="space2"> <div class="divider"> <div class="c-hr"><hr class="ie-fix"></div></div>

<div id="room_details_holder">
<div id="room_name_and_close"><button class="room_details_close">X</button>    </div>
<div class="room_details">
<div id="rooms_nav_bar"><button class="room_previous"><<</button>
<div class="room_name"><div id="room_name"></div></div>
<button class="room_next">>></button></div>

<div class="room_exp" title="Room Type 1" data-room="one" data-number="1">
  <div class="room_split_l"><div id="room1_photo"><img src="site-assets/photos/rooms1.jpg"></div> <div class="book"></div> </div>
  <div class="room_split_r"><div class="room_description"> </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="room_exp" title="Room Type 2" data-room="two" data-number="2">
  <div class="room_split_l"><div id="room2_photo"><img src="site-assets/photos/rooms2.jpg"></div> <div class="book"></div> </div>
  <div class="room_split_r"><div class="room_description"> </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="room_exp" title="Room Type 3" data-room="three" data-number="3">
  <div class="room_split_l"><div id="room3_photo"><img src="site-assets/photos/rooms3.jpg"></div> <div class="book"></div> </div>
  <div class="room_split_r"><div class="room_description"> </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="room_exp" title="Room Type 4" data-room="four" data-number="4">
  <div class="room_split_l"><div id="room4_photo"><img src="room-category/attic/img1.jpg"></div> <div class="book"></div> </div>
  <div class="room_split_r"><div class="room_description"> </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="room_exp" title="Room Type 5" data-room="five" data-number="5">
  <div class="room_split_l"><div id="room5_photo"><img src="room-category/neweds/IMG_9441.JPG"></div> <div class="book"></div> </div>
  <div class="room_split_r"><div class="room_description"> </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="room_exp" title="Room Type 6" data-room="six" data-number="6">
  <div class="room_split_l"><div id="room6_photo"></div> <div class="book">    </div> </div>
  <div class="room_split_r"><div class="room_description"> </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="room_exp" title="Room Type 7" data-room="seven" data-number="7">
  <div class="room_split_l"><div id="room5_photo"><img src="room-category/neweds/IMG_9441.JPG"></div> <div class="book"></div> </div>
  <div class="room_split_r"><div class="room_description"> </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="room_exp" title="Room Type 8" data-room="eight" data-number="8">
```

Here's the full javascript below:

```
$(".room_mdts").click(function(event){
//get the target 
var target = event.currentTarget;
var room = $(target).data("room");

//First way, by reuse target (only inside this function)
$('#room_details_holder').show();
//The second, by using selectors

 //remove all "selected" classes to all which have both "room" and "selected" classes
  $('.room_exp.selected').removeClass("selected");
  //add "selected" class to the current room (the selector can also be the target variable)
  $('.room_exp[data-room='+room+']').addClass("selected");
});




var currentIndex = 0,
 items = $('.room_details .room_exp'),
 itemAmt = items.length;

function cycleItems() {
  var item = $('.room_details .room_exp').eq(currentIndex);
  items.hide();
  item.css('display','inline-block');
}


$('.room_next').click(function() {
  currentIndex += 1;
  if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  cycleItems();
});

$('.room_previous').click(function() {
  currentIndex -= 1;
  if (currentIndex < 0) {
    currentIndex = itemAmt - 1;
  }
  cycleItems();
  $('#room_name').text($('.room_exp:nth-child('+    (currentIndex+1)+')').attr('title'));
});

$('.room_next').click(function(){
$('#room_name').text($('.room_exp:nth-child('+(currentIndex+1)+')').attr('title'));
});
$('.room_previous').click(function(){
$('#room_name').text($('.room_exp:nth-child('+(currentIndex-1)+')').attr('title'));
});
$('#room_name').text($('[style*="inline-block"].room_exp').attr('title'));


});
```

The code seems long, but is full of repetitions, I have tried to make sure it's sufficient. So, is there a way of writing

```
 var CurrentIndex = $(target).data("room")
```

(of course using numbers in the data-room, which I have tried, but didn't work!)

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/ekh20dxz/2/

Comment: could you create a working jsfiddle with your problem?

Comment: What is `.room_mdts`?
I do not see anywhere in this class

Comment: .room_mdts is in every line of the first block of html, you just need to scroll right. Sorry, it's kinda hard too see, but it's a complex structure =(

Comment: Here's the jfiddle analogue (haha!) http://classikhotel.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

working solution JSfiddle, check comments below for details

jsfiddle.net/4x48441L/24/

Comment: Okay, so from the looks of it you've just moved the currentIndex to the first block of javascript, but would the variable be defined in the next function though? I'll try and let you know!

Comment: Also, I believe i need to have 
    var CurrentIndex = $(target).data("number");

as opposed to just currentIndex = ..., right?

Comment: u dont want to redefine the variable everytime the user clicks on an image, just define it at the top once only.

Comment: Doesn't work =( It does open the right expanded slide, but clicks next/previous cause the display:none; and no next/previous slide appears

Comment: If you put all your code into a jsfiddle I can fix it for you. Quite hard to explain via comments

Comment: Is it possible to do something like: 
      currentIndex = 0,
      currentIndex = $('.room_exp .selected').data("room");
so that the clicked expanded slide that takes class .selected gives the data-room="some number" to the currentIndex?

Comment: Okay, I will try to put a fiddle up, might take me some time tho =)

Comment: you don't need to over complicate things, since you are already querying which image the user has clicked on, you simply need to pass that information onto the currentIndex variable and then base the rest of your functions on the value of currentIndex.

Comment: Added a Fiddle, but the slider shifted downwards for some reason, so might be easier to see the javascript functionality in the console =(
No idea what went wrong with the positioning!

EDITED: Okay, slider works now

Comment: yes, works perfectly, with the exception that the slides moved under their container, but the functionality remains perfectly accurate. Click on "More Info" - the black area would contain the corresponging slide. Next/previous works. But what doesn't work is what I am trying to achieve! =) The errors are only about the files that couldn't be loaded (pictures only, no scripts) since I've coppied the code directly from the web-site. 

Here is how it supposed to look on the page: http://classikhotel.com/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4x48441L/24/    Here you go :) A few things to note is that you need to access the attribute (data-room) for the number of the panel you are on, but that is returned as a string so you need to change it into a number first. Otherwise when you do currentIndex += 1, if currentIndex = '6', you will get 61 not 7. Then the control condition will reset currentIndex to 0 since 61 > itemAmt. I didn't remove the console logs so you can see for yourself

Comment: Yes! That's what I've asked a bunch of people about, I was very suspicious that it reads as a string as I have encountered the same problem with some statistical software! But no one replied to this on stackoverflow! I shall check and let you know!

Comment: Okay, next definitely works, how do I tweak previous? I've tried to add console.log (no idea what it does) to the previous, but it doesn't work at all. And any ideas how to fix the title, so that it shows upon expanding and not after next/previous is selected? 
I am sorry for sounding dumb - I am very noob with javascript!

Comment: Pretty much the same thing as next! Figure this one out yourself :) The console.logs are just there for debugging, they don't actually do anything

Comment: Ah I see! Cool! Any idea or leads of how to display the title as soon as the slide is expanded?)
And thank you so much, man! You're the most helping person on this website I've encountered so far!

Comment: I've just realised that upon clicking next - it jumps  +2 slides instead of one, not to mention that I still can't figure out how to fix the title! Oh, why is this so complicated? Haha

Comment: with the title update, you need to run some code to update the title in the event listener for the previous, next buttons and on .room_mdts. With the +2 slides you just need to check the maths and logic. Spend some time looking at what each function does. It will only get easier with more experience!

Comment: That's the thing! I tried to adjust the +2 slides problem by adding a new variable, but now it only goes further once, after which the next button has no effect. Tried to do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/80em4drd/2/